# Homebrew: Install through a config file similar to pip's requirements.txt?

Tags: macos, pip, homebrew

As title, with Python's `pip`, you could do:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

to batch install packages with specified versions.

Does Homebrew have the same system?

I quickly browsed `brew`'s man page and couldn't find obvious switches.

Comment: I just upvoted this, because it asked and answered a question I had. Not sure why this was '-1'... but now it is '0'. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Homebrew Bundle](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-bundle/) is the preferred way.

```
brew bundle dump
brew bundle
```

Comment: I don't get it. Where's the file, what does it look like?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.
For example you can update brew.txt whatever you want.

```
brew list > brew.txt
<brew.txt xargs brew install
```

### For specific versions

```
node 5.5.0
node4-lts 4.3.1
```

Comment: @kakyo Is everyting ok?